# How to mock entrySet in java - junit

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit, junit4

I have a class with constructor as below and i am trying to mock those input params from junit

```
public CacheConfigurationProcessor{
    public CacheConfigurationProcessor(@NonNull Map<String, String> allThemeConfigurations,
                                       @NonNull Map<String, String> allCacheConfigurations,
                                       @NonNull MetricsManager metricsManager,
                                       @NonNull cacheManager productSearchModelCacheManager) {
        this.allThemeConfigurations = allThemeConfigurations;
        this.allCacheConfigurations = allCacheConfigurations;
        this.metricsManager = metricsManager;
        this.cacheManager = CacheManager;
    
        processCacheConfigurationForThemes();
    }


        @SneakyThrows
        private void processCacheConfigurationForThemes() {
    
            System.out.println("allThemeConfigurations " + allThemeConfigurations.entrySet()); //this is empty
     
            for (Map.Entry<String, String> singleThemeConfiguration : allThemeConfigurations.entrySet()) {
    
         system.out.println(singleThemeConfiguration)
    }
        }

public static void TestMyFeature(){
some random logic
}

}
```

Junit

```
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
    public class CacheConfigurationProcessorTest{
    
        @Mock
        private Map<String, String> ALL_ORIGINAL_CACHE_CONFIGURATIONS;
        @Mock
        private Map<String, String> allThemeConfigMock;
        @Mock
        private MetricsManager metricsManager;
        @Mock
        private CacheManager CacheManagerMock;
    
        @InjectMocks
        private CacheConfigurationProcessor cacheConfigurationProcessor;
    
        @Before
        public void init() throws Exception {
            // Mock the behavior of entrySet()
            Set<Map.Entry<String, String>> mockEntrySet = getAllThemeConfig().entrySet();
            when(allThemeConfigMock.entrySet()).thenReturn(mockEntrySet);
       }
    
        @Test
        public void someTest(){
    
        CacheConfigurationProcessor.TestMyFeature()
      }
    }
```

Expected : Since i mocked `allThemeConfigMock` i expected

```
    System.out.println("allThemeConfigurations " + allThemeConfigurations.entrySet()); //Expected to print mocked map
```

This would print mocked map , however i am getting empty response here

```
    System.out.println("allThemeConfigurations " + allThemeConfigurations.entrySet()); //this is empty as []
```

What is the issue and Why the map I mocked is not working as expected.

Thanks

Comment: As a rule of thumb one should never mock types which one doesn't own. Use a real map implementation and your tests will be a lot simpler. And probably you can also use a concrete implementation of CacheManager and MetricsManager. I would also suggest you to read the article [Mocks are not Stubs](https://martinfowler.com/articles/mocksArentStubs.html) to learn about other types of test doubles.